# Why are my values not replaced in CSV files using np.nan?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

I am new to python and I'm having trouble with changing values below a certain threshold in a CSV file to NaNs.

The script that I have worked fine for one dataset, but not the other. The main difference between these datasets are the dimensions of the CSV file: 1800 rows x 13 columns vs 1800 rows x 28 columns. The columns contain x-, y-position, and a likelihood value for different body parts derived from video analysis.

This is the code that I use, to check if the values in the CSV file are changed tot NaN.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
  

absolute_path = 'mypath/example.csv'
p_cutoff = 0.9

df = pd.read_csv(absolute_path, header=[1,2], index_col=0)

print(df.head)

print('before: ')
print(df.isna().sum())

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if df.loc[i]['arm_L']['likelihood'] < p_cutoff:
        df.loc[i]['arm_L']['x'] = np.nan
        df.loc[i]['arm_L']['y'] = np.nan

print('')
print('after: ')
print(df.isna().sum())

print(df.head)
```

Changing the x and y-coordinates to nan works when the data frame has 13 columns, but when I try it on a data frame with even just one extra column (i.e. more body parts) the x- y-values are not replaced.

Does anybody know how to solve this?

[Example narrow data frame:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWykg.png)

[Example wide data frame:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L785t.png)

[Expected outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlA9Z.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is because the way the method loc works with more than one column, although you could make it your way with minor changes it will compute faster if you use the     import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

```
absolute_path = 'mypath/example.csv'
p_cutoff = 0.9

df = pd.read_csv(absolute_path, header=[1,2], index_col=0)

print(df.head)

print('before: ')
print(df.isna().sum())

for col in ['x', 'y']
    df['arm_L'][col] = np.where(df['arm_L']['likelihood'] < p_cutoff, 
                                np.nan, df['arm_L'][col])

print('')
print('after: ')
print(df.isna().sum())

print(df.head)
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be faster but I still don't get nan in the wide data frame.